# filter results in an array of objects just like operator(%oil%) using lodash

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, arrays, lodash

I want to filter array of objects based on the input change by the user and create a new array of matched array of objects using LODASH (https://lodash.com/).

```
let listing = [{title: "Courier/Logistics", id: 1, totalWorkers: 1058, openPositions: 0, omani: 99.72},
{title: "Information Technology", id: 1, totalWorkers: 2, openPositions: 1, omani: 50},
{title: "Oil & Gas", id: 1, totalWorkers: 98, openPositions: 6, omani: 91.84}];
```

I have tried lodash `_.filter` but this filters exact words and exact case and then return that single searched value.

```
const filtered = _.filter(listing, function(o) {
        return o.title === "oi";
      });
      console.log(filtered);
```

I want to get results just like we do in mysql as:

```
WHERE title like %oi%
```

and it gives matched values which contained that input.

Thanks

Comment: `===` means it has to be same. If you want to do partial check, use `.indexOf`. Try `o.title.indexOf('ol')> -1` or use regex `/ol/i.test(o.title)`

Comment: I have tried `==` as well.

Comment: `===` and `==` check for complete value. What you need is a partial check. Hence regex or indexOf

Comment: You need to correct your predicate, instead of checking with` ===` check using `indexOf` method. like `_.filter(listing, v => v.title.indexOf('oi') != -1);`

Comment: Thanks Rajesh. Great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see the snippet, 
used to lowerCase to match all string in upper and lower case,
in your example, your string "Oil & Gas" is in Camel case and when you try to match the string it will always result in blank array.

```js
let listing = [{title: "Courier/Logistics", id: 1, totalWorkers: 1058, openPositions: 0, omani: 99.72},
{title: "Information Technology", id: 1, totalWorkers: 2, openPositions: 1, omani: 50},
{title: "Oil & Gas", id: 1, totalWorkers: 98, openPositions: 6, omani: 91.84}];
const filtered = _.filter(listing, function(o) {
  return o.title.toLowerCase().indexOf("oi") > -1;
});
console.log(filtered);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please note that its a bad practice to answer a duplicate question. Right way to handle such posts is by marking/sharing duplicate link.

Answer (score 1):

In your filter function, use the includes function
ie

```
return o.title.includes("oi");
```

Comment: You do not need `.*`. Just check if `oi` is present or not.

Comment: Also, just a pointer, such basic questions are already answered. Instead of answering them, we should look for similar posts and mark them as duplicate instead

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `lodash` for that at all,

just use this using regular expression and native filter:

`listing.filter(o=>o.title.match(/oi/i))`